# Is there a way to include i + 1 in a for loop within a broadcast class function?

Tags: java, android, arrays, parsing, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to loop through a string array containing numbers and parse these values into an integer collection, displaying the return value into a broadcast e.g. "A work from ---, returned value" .

I've split the string into a string array with `.split(',')` and attempted to loop through this array while parsing the string values to integers.
I can get a return value from the for loop if I can directly enter the index `parseInt(FilterDataValues[1])` or any index indexed, but once I add i `parseInt(FilterDataValues[i+1])` or `parseInt(FilterDataValues[i])` I can't get a return value. The loop works fine in a simpler loop, so I'm not too sure what's going on. Please help me any help will be fine

```
 public String sortingList(Context context)
    {
        String filterData = "";
        StimulusDatabase td = new StimulusDatabase(context);

        Cursor result = td.getAllData();
        while (result.moveToNext())
        {
            filterData = (result.getString(23));
        }

        if(filterData.isEmpty())
        {
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            String[] FilterDataValues = filterData.split(",");

            for(int i = 0; i <= FilterDataValues.length; i++)
            {
                FilterOptions.add(parseInt(FilterDataValues[i+1]));
            }

//            for(int i = 0; i <= FilterDataValues.length; i++)
//            {
//                FilterOptions.add(i+1));
//            }

            return filterData;
        }
    }
```

Output of the entire code doesn't cause a notification to appear even after 20/30 minutes

Output when using the commented code (0,2,6 are column indexes)

```
A word from Martin Luther King Jr
0,2,6
```

The entire class is below

```
package com.example.MentalHealthStateManagement.Application.Notifications;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.MentalHealthStateManagement.Application.Database.StimulusDatabase;
import com.example.MentalHealthStateManagement.R;
import com.example.MentalHealthStateManagement.StateHandler.CheckIn;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

public class Trigger_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "M.H.S.M daily check-in registry";
    private static final String TAG = "Trigger Receiver: ";

    private String[] authors;
    private String sortStatement;
    private List<Integer> FilterOptions = new ArrayList<>();
    private int notificationID = 135;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        sortStatement = sortingList(context);
        authors = getAuthors(context).split("#");
        String[] quotes = getQuotes(context).split("#");

        int randomNum = randomPosition();

        // Create an exclusive intent for the user's daily check-in
        intent = new Intent(context, CheckIn.class);

        // Create the TaskStack Builder and add the Main Activity, which inflates the back stack
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Checks if the API Level is 26 or greater
        Notification.Builder notification = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notification = new Notification.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                    .setContentTitle("A word from " + authors[randomNum])
                    .setContentText(sortingList(context))//quotes[randomNum]
                    .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(sortingList(context)))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
        }

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManger = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        assert notification != null;
        notificationManger.notify(notificationID, notification.build());
        notificationID++;
        Log.i("Trigger_Receiver", "Trigger successful");
    }

    //Gets the authors for the specified trigger
    public String getAuthors(Context context)
    {
        StringBuilder authors = new StringBuilder();
        StimulusDatabase td = new StimulusDatabase(context);
       // List<Integer> AuthorsToBeFiltered = NumberFilterValue;

        Cursor result = td.getAllData();

            while (result.moveToNext())
            {
                authors = new StringBuilder(result.getString(2) + " " + result.getString(4) + " "
                        + result.getString(6) + " " + result.getString(8) + " " +
                            result.getString(10) + " " + result.getString(12) + " "
                        + result.getString(14) + " " + result.getString(16) + " " +
                            result.getString(18) + " " + result.getString(20));
            }

//            while (result.moveToNext())
//            {
//                if(!AuthorsToBeFiltered.isEmpty())
//                {
//                    for(int i = 0; i<AuthorsToBeFiltered.size(); i++)
//                    {
//                        if(AuthorsToBeFiltered.get(i) % 2 == 0)
//                        {
//                            authors.append(result.getString(i));
//                        }
//                    }
//                }
//                else
//                {
//                    authors = new StringBuilder(result.getString(2) + " " + result.getString(4) + " " + result.getString(6) + " " + result.getString(8) + " " +
//                            result.getString(10) + " " + result.getString(12) + " " + result.getString(14) + " " + result.getString(16) + " " +
//                            result.getString(18) + " " + result.getString(20));
//                }
//            }

        return authors.toString();
    }

    //Gets the quotes for the specified trigger
    public String getQuotes(Context context)
    {
        StringBuilder quotes = new StringBuilder();
        StimulusDatabase td = new StimulusDatabase(context);
        //List<Integer> AuthorsToBeFiltered = NumberFilterValue;

        Cursor result = td.getAllData();

                while (result.moveToNext())
                {
                    quotes.append(result.getString(1)).append(" ").append(result.getString(3))
                            .append(" ").append(result.getString(5)).append(" ").append(result.getString(7))
                            .append(" ").append(result.getString(9)).append(" ").append(result.getString(11))
                            .append(" ").append(result.getString(13)).append(" ").append(result.getString(15))
                            .append(" ").append(result.getString(17)).append(" ").append(result.getString(19));
                }

//            while (result.moveToNext())
//            {
//                if(!AuthorsToBeFiltered.isEmpty())
//                {
//                    for(int i = 0; i<AuthorsToBeFiltered.size(); i++)
//                    {
//                        if(AuthorsToBeFiltered.get(i) % 2 == 0)
//                        {
//                            quotes.append(result.getString(i-1));
//                        }
//                    }
//                }
//                else
//                {
//                    quotes.append(result.getString(1)).append(" ").append(result.getString(3))
//                            .append(" ").append(result.getString(5)).append(" ").append(result.getString(7))
//                            .append(" ").append(result.getString(9)).append(" ").append(result.getString(11))
//                            .append(" ").append(result.getString(13)).append(" ").append(result.getString(15))
//                            .append(" ").append(result.getString(17)).append(" ").append(result.getString(19));
//                }
//            }

        return quotes.toString();
    }

    //A random number used to gather different quotes and authors
    //P.S. each quote belongs to appropriate author due to the delimiter settings preformed in the StimulusSetup class
    public Integer randomPosition()
    {
        int randomNum = 0;
        // Ensures the API level 26 or greater
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, authors.length + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"Incompatible device, API lower than lollipop");
        }
        return randomNum;
    }

    public String sortingList(Context context)
    {
        String filterData = "";
        StimulusDatabase td = new StimulusDatabase(context);

        Cursor result = td.getAllData();
        while (result.moveToNext())
        {
            filterData = (result.getString(23));
        }

        if(filterData.isEmpty())
        {
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            String[] FilterDataValues = filterData.split(",");

            for(int i = 0; i <= FilterDataValues.length; i++)
            {
                FilterOptions.add(parseInt(FilterDataValues[i+1]));
            }

//  `         Working loop
//            for(int i = 0; i <= FilterDataValues.length; i++)
//            {
//                FilterOptions.add(i+1));
//            }

            return filterData;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in the loop, you are calling

`FilterOptions.add(parseInt(FilterDataValues[i+1]));`

which should fail in last interation of loop, because there will be attempt of reading value from position which does not exist in this array. I guess you could find `IndexOutOfBoundException` in LogCat.

This is probably the cause of why you can't get return value, as method should throw exception.

Comment: I understand why I'd get an ```IndexOutOfBoundException``` because evenutally I'll be at the final index trying to go a step above, but without ```i+1``` just using the index ```i```, there's no return value being shown. That's my current issues if It wasn't stated in the OP I apologize